# Pandas not working when running code from a text editor

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6

I have a Python 3.6 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| installation. When I import pandas in shell mode in the command window or in IPython, it works fine.

The code I tried to run was pretty simple

```
import pandas as pd

animals = ['Tiger', 'Bear', 'Moose']
print(pd.Series(animals))
```

However, when I write the code using notepad++ and call it from the command window (e.g., python text.py), it throws up the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "series_intro.py", line 1, in <module> import pandas as pd
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 37,
in <module>
import pandas.core.config_init
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py",
line 18, in <module>
from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", li
ne 33, in <module>
from pandas.io.common import _get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 40
7, in <module>
def UnicodeReader(f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
```

Please help.

Tried a suggestion from a response on this thread and modified the code to

```
import csv
print(csv.__file__)
import pandas as pd


animals = ['Tiger', 'Bear', 'Moose']
print(pd.Series(animals))
```

The following traceback error occurs:

```
C:\Users\k\Dropbox\data science>python panda_intro.py
C:\Users\k\Dropbox\data science\csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panda_intro.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 37,
 in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\config_init.py",
line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", li
ne 33, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 40
7, in <module>
    def UnicodeReader(f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
```

Comment: Provide your code too, so it is more likely to get help.

Comment: The code I tried to run was pretty simple

import pandas

animals = ['Tiger', 'Bear', 'Moose']
print(pd.Series(animals))

Comment: Just change this: `Import pandas as pd`

Comment: sorry the code had that already. Still same traceback

Comment: Unexpected AttributeErrors are usually the result of shadowing one module with another.  Could you add `import csv`, `print(csv.__file__)` before the `import pandas as pd` line and edit your question to include the result?

Comment: @Kels: I meant include the result of the `print` -- we're trying to find out whether you're importing the right `csv` module.

Comment: @DSM: I have modified the output to include the result of the `print`